# get_companies limiting locations output to 5?

Tags: python, api, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get all the locations that a company in LinkedIn has, but it seems that it's limiting to only 5.  What are the params that I need to change to increase the number of locations returned?

For example, my company, Slalom Consulting, has about 15 locations, but it's only returning 5.  I can't get that second '_total' to increase above 5.

```
app.get_companies(company_ids=[166000], selectors=['name', 'locations'], params={})

{
 "_total": 1, 
 "values": [
  {
   "_key": "166000", 
   "locations": {
    "_total": 5, 
    "values": [
     {
      "contactInfo": {
       "fax": "", 
       "phone1": "206 483 5700"
      }, 
      "address": {
       "postalCode": "98104", 
       "city": "Seattle", 
       "street1": "Suite 1900"
      }
     }, 
     {
      "contactInfo": {
       "fax": "310-322-6888", 
       "phone1": "310-322-6800"
      }, 
      "address": {
       "postalCode": "90245", 
       "city": "El Segundo", 
       "street1": "Suite 600"
      }
     }, 
     {
      "contactInfo": {
       "fax": "415-593-3451", 
       "phone1": "415-593-3450"
      }, 
      "address": {
       "postalCode": "94105", 
       "city": "San Francisco", 
       "street1": "Suite 1550"
      }
     }, 
     {
      "contactInfo": {
       "fax": "972-294-7301", 
       "phone1": "972-294-7300"
      }, 
      "address": {
       "postalCode": "75024", 
       "city": "Plano", 
       "street1": "Suite 480"
      }
     }, 
     {
      "contactInfo": {
       "fax": "312.329.0461", 
       "phone1": "312.329.0401"
      }, 
      "address": {
       "postalCode": "60601", 
       "city": "Chicago", 
       "street1": "Suite 5300"
      }
     }
    ]
   }, 
   "name": "Slalom Consulting"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Post your code, please.

Comment: I guess app is defined with a library you import. Which library? You need to post more code for us to be able to help you.

Comment: code added below - as stated connecting to linkedin API.

Answer (score 0):

I know that I need to add some params, but not sure what I need to do to get locations more than 5.

```
from linkedin import linkedin 
import json
import csv

##start connection to LinkedIn
CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxx'
USER_TOKEN = 'xxx'
USER_SECRET = 'xxx'
RETURN_URL = '' # Not required for developer authentication
# Instantiate the developer authentication class
auth = linkedin.LinkedInDeveloperAuthentication(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, USER_TOKEN, USER_SECRET,RETURN_URL, permissions=linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())

app = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(auth)

co = app.get_companies(company_ids=[166000], selectors=['name', 'locations'], params={})
print co
```